# How to get repeating request parameters in Compojure

Tags: clojure, compojure

I can get to the request parameters easily with:

```
(:foo params)
```

However, when I have a request like this:

```
/api?foo=1&foo=2&foo=3
```

I only get back `"3"` while I would expect an array `["1","2","3"]`.

I'm not sure why this is happening because when I look at the code in:

https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring-codec/blob/master/src/ring/util/codec.clj#L128

It seems to call `assoc-conj` which is supposed to turn multiple params of the same name into a vector containing the values.

Am I missing something here or is this a bug?

Comment: The link talks about POST data in www-form-urlencoded form. Your query is about query string. By the way, isn't it weird to pass same query string 3 times ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use a standard Clojure destructuring form:

```
(GET "/api" {{:strs [foo]} :query-params} (str foo))

curl "http://localhost:3000/api?foo=1&foo=2&foo=3" 
==> ["1" "2" "3"]
```

doc: https://github.com/weavejester/compojure/wiki/Destructuring-Syntax

Answer (score 0):

I've never encountered this issue myself, but if it is indeed impossible to get a hold of the multiple values without manually parsing the URL yourself, it sounds like it's worth filing a bug report over at https://github.com/weavejester/compojure/. (Unless it's a feature.. There are some other things in Compojure and Clout that's a bit non-standard but highly convenient.)